# Dynamically load xhtml page in <p:tab> using EL

Tags: jsf, primefaces

all
 I am using primefaces-3.0.M3 jar, i want load xhtml page inside  
 I have tired following code,but it is not working

```
                    <p:tabView id="tabview"
                               value="#{HomeBean.tabList}"
                               var="pageUrl"
                               binding="#{HomeBean.tabView}"
                               cache="true" widgetVar="tabviewV">

                        <p:tab id="tab"  title="#{pageUrl}" closable="true" >

                            <ui:include src="#{pageUrl}"/>

                        </p:tab>

                    </p:tabView>
```

Code in HomeBean.java

```
private List<String> tabList = new ArrayList<String>();

public HomeBean(){
      tabList.add("Test1.xhtml");
      tabList.add("Test2.xhtml");
      tabList.add("Test3.xhtml");
}

public List<String> getTabList() {

    return tabList;
}

public void setTabList(List<String> tabList) {
    this.tabList = tabList;
}
```

Please give me solution.
Thx in advanced.

Comment: How did it "not work"? What errors did you get?

Comment: It is an old thread, but i run into this issue today. Your example wont work because ui:insert is rendered only once in time the whole page is rendering so all the tabs will have same content (content of the first tab). Did you resolve this problem some how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got solution for this and it is working fine

```
<p:tabView id="tabview" 
     value="#{HomeBean.tabList}" 
     var="pageUrl" cache="true" 
     widgetVar="tabviewV">

    <p:tab id="tab"  title="#{pageUrl}" >
      <iframe src="#{pageUrl}" width="100%" height="572px" style="border-width: 0PX;">
      </iframe>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Comment: spent so much time trying to get it to work!  this is so simple and works!  now to get the iframe to fill panel and grow with it as the window resizes.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and I saw that `#{pageUrl}` was null even though there were items in the `tabList`. You can try this way:

```
<p:tabView id="tabview" widgetVar="tabview" binding="#{HomeBean.tabView}">

   <c:forEach items="#{HomeBean.tabList}" var="pageUrl">

      <p:tab title="#{pageUrl}"   >
         <ui:include src="#{pageUrl}" />
      </p:tab>

   </c:forEach>

</p:tabView>
```